# How many subsets following the statement

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let **$A$$=${$1,2,3...,n$}.**
How many subsets of $B\subseteq A$ following the statement:
**$B\space \cap \space ${$1,2,3$}$=${$1,2$}**

My way of thinking:
there are $2^n$ subsets available to choose, but there are 3 type of subsets that are not allowed:

1) Subsets that starts from $n\ge2$, e.g. $\space$ {$2,3...n$}, {$3,4...n$}..

2)Subsets that contain {$3$}, e.g. {$1,2,3..$}, {$1,2,3,4..$}..

3) Subsets that doesn't contain {$2$}, e.g. {$1,3,4...$}..

Now I want to decrease those options from $2^n$ but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ needs to be of the form $ \{1,2\} \cup X$ where $X \subset \{ 4,\cdots ,n\}$ there are $2^{n-3}$ choices for $X$ and therefore $\color{blue}{2^{n-3}}$ choices for $B$.

Answer (score 4):

What we know about those subsets $B $ is that $1\in B $, $2\in B $ and $3\notin B $. For all the other elements $4,\ldots,n $ there are no requirements, they may belong to $B $ or not, thus the number of possibilities is $2^{n-3} $.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think in the opposite direction:

We have $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$.

Let's create new set, $A_0=A\setminus\{3\}$

So $A_0=\{1,2,4,5,\cdots,n\}$

We have $2^{n-1}$ subset to this set

Now, supposed we have the set $\{1,2\}$ as a constant, if they are constant I can rewrite $A_0$ like the following: $A_0=\{1,2\}+A_1$, where $A_1=\{4,5,\cdots,n\}$, so the answer is the amount of subset of $A_1$ which is $2^{n-3}$

Comment: While I appreciate different methods (+1), I find this method to be slightly more lengthy and difficult to understand, than the other straightforward approach. Still, there is no harm in having another method.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I find this way the easiest way to understand, I guess everyone has different ways to look at this

Comment: Yes, you're right.